# Comments Module - edit comments

Tags: ee2, members, comments

Using the native Comments Module, I have a comments form and entries on a page with a single blog entry.

I am attempting to add an edit button to allow users to edit their comments on the front-end.

The edit link works fine for a Super Admin. According to the [EE documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/comment/index.html#editing-permissions), I should be able to edit as a regular member as long as that member is logged in, the author of the comment, and the editing time limit must not have expired.

I have all 3 of those conditions met, yet nothing within the {if editable} renders.

any insight would be appreciated.

update:
My setup

```
{!-- jQuery is included in <head> --}
{exp:comment:edit_comment_script}
<ul id="posted-comments">
    {exp:comment:entries sort="asc" limit="20"}
        <li class="comment" id="comment_{comment_id}">
            <span class="comment_body">{comment}</span>
            {if editable}
                <a href="#" class="edit_link">Edit</a>
                <div class="editCommentBox" style="display:none;">
                    <textarea cols="70" rows="8">{comment_stripped}</textarea><br />
                    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="cancel_edit">
                    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="submit_edit">
                </div>
            {/if}
            <p class="info">
                <span class="name">By {name}</span>
                <span class="date">on {comment_date format="%m/%d/%Y"}</span>
            </p>
        </li>
    {/exp:comment:entries}
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant snippet of code?

Comment: are you getting any Javascript console errors?

Comment: No, I do not get any javascript errors.
It seems to be an issue with the Member Group Type 'Members'.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to check:

- Is the {exp:comment:edit_comment_script} tag in your header or in your template? The docs don't say specifically but I'd guess it needs to be in your header.
- Check to see what the variable {editable} actually prints out if anything
- Check to see what the variable {can_moderate_comment} actually prints out if anything
- Under [Comment Administration Privileges](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html#comment-administration-privileges) for the member group preferences, make sure "Can edit comments in their own channel entries" is turned on. For the heck of it, turn on all options in that section.
- Make sure the member you are logged is as when attempting to edit is the same member who posted the comment